Getting 403 when trying to access SVN repos using Apache dav_svn configuration
I have installed svn on an EC2 ubuntu server, hosted via apache2.
I have adjusted the /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf file with the following configuration:
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn

  SVNParentPath /var/svn/repos
  SVNListParentPath on

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users

  <IfModule mod_authz_svn.c>
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/authz
  </IfModule>

  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>

The repos are located in the following directory: /var/svn/repos and have the following permission settings:
drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 30 05:14 repo1
drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 24 00:01 repo2

The issue appears to be related to authentication, specifically in my authz file. If I comment out the following in my dav_svn.conf file, users can access the repos with no issue.:
  <IfModule mod_authz_svn.c>
    #AuthzSVNAccessFile "/etc/subversion/authz"
  </IfModule>

I have a very simple /etc/subversion/authz file, which I have checked to ensure has no special/extra characters:
[repo1:/]
user1=rw
*=

If i change the 3rd line to be *=rw, I am able to access the repo - it's just individual user access that is not being authorized
I have created and confirmed the associated users in the /etc/svn-auth-users file.
Here is output from the /var/log/apache2/access.log:
70.71.112.244 - - [05/Dec/2024:20:25:41 +0000] "GET /svn/repo1/ HTTP/1.1" 403 524 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Can anyone provide guidance on what I might be missing to enable proper authentication for my SVN Server.

How are the users authenticated?
